# laravel chart JS dynamic label from array

Tags: laravel, charts

I have an array $v from a controller like this:

```
array(5) { 
[0]=> string(3) "SB" 
[1]=> string(4) "SES" 
[2]=> string(4) "SLS" 
[3]=> string(4) "SLS" 
[4]=> string(4) "SPH" 
}
```

and a chart:

```
var ChartX = new Chart($chart, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['SCX', 'BDX'], //$v Here how??
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Counter',
        data: v
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

I was able to view data for datasets: data from a int array but cannot do the same for the labels using the above array. Please help

Comment: The array you posted is 2 different arrays. How are you using the array in your javascript? Does it come from a controller?

Comment: Sorry..wrong array..i updated it..and yes it's coming from a controller..for the data part i used ```json_encode($v)```but doesn't work on the label

Comment: Try `JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($v) }}')`

Comment: shows undefined

Comment: Use console.log to see if the value is an array or not. console.log (json_encode) should give you a string. JSON.parse( json string) should give you a js array.

Comment: never mind i solved it myself without ```JSON.parse('{{ json_encode($v) }}')```